# ACL rights on controller method using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, acl, rights

I am trying to check some permissions when a user access to a page and redirect him to an error page (controller specific) when I hasn't got good rights.
I know Spring Security and Pre/PostAuthorize annotations but my application do not need any login form even less UserService.

My permissions are defined by injecting an user context (combinating some data create user rights).

So my idea is to annotate Spring Controller method with an "Permission" annotation and create an annotation processor who verify user user rights on request (and redirect him if have no rights).
Is it a good idea and how to declare this annotation processor with Spring MVC ?

Comment: Why can't you use Spring Security?  You are basically describing how most of SSO works...pass in some pre-auth data to let the app server know you have already authenticated the user.  Then you don't have to write any custom annotations.

Comment: Ok, which handlers should I have to create and configure to do that (custom role validation / custom access denied handler) ?

Comment: It's been a while since I had to do this myself, but I think you want to create a custom `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and maybe a custom `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` which will use the credentials passed in from the remote app to authenticate the user.  The rest should use the standard Spring Security mechanisms.